# What impact does squaring a dependent variable have in a model?

Tags: predictor

I am performing some regression here to study the association between the length of time an auditor has been auditing a company and the choice of auditor. In this case, my DV is auditor tenure (TENURE) and IV is auditor choice which is dichotomous, among other controls. I have performed regression using this variable against the relevant predictors and got useful results. Upon reading the literature, I came across an instance where the variable TENURE is squared but could not figure out what are the implications of squaring it on the DV-IV relationship. The literature is not clear either. Could someone assist in explaining this to me please?

Comment: Tenure is usually squared when it is an **independent** variable,at least in the economics literature, in order to calculate the "reverse-U shape" between tenure and other labor related variables. Not sure squaring tenure when it is a dependent variable has much sense in your context. Have you considered inverting your two variables? That would make more economic and econometric sense.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a domain specific intuition, all it means is that you are trying to linearize the following model $$y=\sqrt{X\beta+\varepsilon}$$ When you square $y$, you get $z=X\beta+\varepsilon$, where $z=y^2$

As with any linearization, you have to be cognizant of the impact on the error terms, i.e. in this case make sure you understand that this model is different from $$y=\sqrt{X\beta}+\varepsilon$$

By domain specific, I meant that sometimes transformations, such as squaring, have their own meaning. For instance, in physics the intensity is a square of the amplitude. The wave equation is $$y=A\sin(\omega t)$$ where $y$ could be the physical property such as electrical field strength. Now, $y^2$ has its own meaning, it's intensity, that's how much power is in the signal. So, we have both $y$ and $y^2$ with meaning, i.e. not merely math transformation for convenience of better data fit